# TRIAC Controlled Motor circuit: PWM logic doubt

Tags: pwm, triac, ac-motor

I'm working on the logic board of my kitchen air extractor. I wanted to "hijack" the controls (physical buttons) to be able to control those with an ESP8266. While I was analyzing the circuit I shorted 220v to one of the motor outputs and everything blew out in my face.

I am planning to rebuild the board from scratch while replacing the original microcontroller with an ESP directly. I bought the original board to be able to keep reverse engineering it. I'm being more careful now, I swear!

I already mapped the crucial parts of the circuit and later wired my logic level analyzer to see the outputs of the original board.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fbut9r.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

This is the schematic I have for now

I'll explain what I figured out on the hardware part:
Load is a 3-speed single phase AC motor. Only two of said speeds are being used: R_LOAD1 which is the lowest resistance coil in the motor (80ohm) and R_LOAD2 which is the HIGHEST resistance coil (120ohm). Speed 2 (100ohm) is not connected to anything.

R_LOAD1 is connected to Tri Sp1&2. Funny thing is that the extractor does have 3 speeds, and they're providing the 1st and 2nd speeds by changing the duty cycle on the PWM that controls the R_LOAD1 Triac.

The following are screenshots of the PWM signal coming out of the HT48R on the respective pins. First two shots are TriSp1&2 (CH1 probe in the circuit) and the third is the pin connected to TriacSp3 (CH0 probe in the circuite).

[image: Speed1]
[image: Speed2]
[image: Speed3]

As you can see, in the first two speeds, the RLOAD_1 is being modulated to ~78.5% duty cycle for the first speed and ~76% for the second speed.
For the third and slowest speed RLOAD_2 is being modulated at 78.5%.

So far so good.. and here I pop my question: My Logic Level analyzer saw both GPIO being high while the extractor motor is off. As you can see in the third picture when I transition from the 2nd speed to the third, the controller turns "off" the RLOAD_1 and starts modulating RLOAD_2, but the GPIO goes HIGH instead of low (which is what I was expecting)... So.. question:

**what it's actually happening?** The triac needs 10mA of current to activate, and according to my calculations it haves 18mA (5v/270ohms) when the pin is HIGH, but how is it turning the triac off if it keeps the ping high?

The pin gets pulled HIGH as soon as I plug the entire thing to mains.

**I captured the PWM signal WITHOUT the motor attached.. so, no voltage was present in the triac's MTs**

[TRIAC Datasheet](https://www.fagorelectronica.com/site/templates/resources/semiconductores/data-sheets/ft16wll.pdf)